# Pagination over Spring Websocket

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-websocket

I have question for Spring Developers ... we are developing intern chatting application where need implement pagination and fetch data when it's needed.

With websockets is created persistent connection with server, so my question is, if it is possible replace rest api with websocket channel, and fetch older messages with ws or use websocket only for realtime data, and loading older messages implement over rest api? If it is possible with ws, can you show me how looks like this controller? Thanks

Comment: did you find the answer to your question? @Denis